# Set notation for a solution to a simple equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

> Solve this equation below and express answer using set notation.
>
> $$|x+3|=9$$

My question really isn't about solving this inequality, it is more about the second part of the question, using set notation to express the answer.

I just put $\{-12, 6\}$ or is there a more correct way?

Comment: Well, anyway you have to express that either $x=-12$ or $x=6$. So you can write
$$
x = 12 \qquad \text{or} \qquad x = 6
$$
or
$$
x \in \{ -12, 6 \}
$$
... and since the question specifically asks for set notation, use the latter.

Comment: Nitpick: That is an _equation_, not an inequality. It has $=$ rather than $<$ or $\le$, etc.

Comment: Yeah you're right @HenningMakholm these are all in the same chapter on inequalities and I got lazy I guess. Cheers.

Comment: @MattiP. can you put your response as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the set of solutions is $\lbrace -12, 6 \rbrace$.